# In Handlebars, how can I access a partial's content from within the partial?

Tags: templates, nested, handlebars.js, partial

From my understanding, the typical use of another partial is this:

```
{{> anotherPartial }}
```

Apparently, Handlebars also supports this notation:

```
{{#> anotherPartial }}
  someContent
{{/ anotherPartial }}
```

**Now, how would I access `someContent` from within `anotherPartial.hbs` to output something like this?**

```
<div class="anotherPartial">someContent</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Handlebars document on Partial Blocks specifies that the template passed to the partial "can be executed by the specially named partial, `@partial-block`. This means that in order to render `someContent`, your `anotherPartial` partial would look like the following:

```
<div class="anotherPartial">
    {{> @partial-block }}
</div>
```

I have created a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/9xope5vw/) in jsFiddle.